# listview for different elements/items

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to implement a `ListView` having an image in the first row and titles on the rest of the items, but its not working. Any solutions for this?

## Here's my code

```
private class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter { 
private Context c;
String titles[];

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String titles[]) {
super(context,R.id.textView1);
this.c = context;
this.titles=titles;
//   this.imagedrawer=imagedrawer;
}   


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;

if(position==0)
{
inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.profileimage,parent,false);
ImageView drawerprofile=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewdrawer);
drawerprofile.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
}
else
{
inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitems,parent,false);
TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv1.setText(titles[position]);
}


return view;  
}`
```

Comment: What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

your not use view in adapter class

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.phote);

return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if (position % 2 == 1) {
 inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.profileimage,parent,false);
 ImageView drawerprofile=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewdrawer);
 drawerprofile.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);

 } else {

 inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitems,parent,false);
 TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 tv1.setText(titles[position]);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView have a Header. You can add the element in Header and TextView in other.

You need reuse the views. Check first the converView is null, only inflate if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the correct View. You are inflating each View in v variable but then you are returning view.

So replace:

```
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitems,parent,false);
```

by

```
view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewitems,parent,false);
```

Also you have to find the views in the inflated view instead of your Activity/Fragment view. I mean use this:

```
ImageView drawerprofile=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewdrawer);
```

instead of:

```
ImageView drawerprofile=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewdrawer);
```

But the best practice here is **use a Header** for your ListView, in this header you can put your ImageView, the rest rows will be returned in the getView method. Also you must to use the ViewHolder pattern in this link you can see how to implent it: [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)